# Query select where date between "1st day of current month" and "current day"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select data from SQL Server database between the 1st day of the current month and current day.

```sql
    SELECT *
      FROM table_name 
     WHERE date BETWEEN "1st day of current month" AND "current day"
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `EOMONTH()` to jump to the last day of the month, of the previous month. Then, just add 1 day, by using `DATEADD()` with 1 as the increment for the day, to get the 1st day of the current month.

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE <date> BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),  -1)) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE_NAME 
 WHERE date BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,date), 0) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you,

```
select * from TABLE_NAME 
where date between 
dateadd (DAY, -(datepart (DAY, getdate ())) + 1, convert (date, GETDATE ())) 
and 
convert (date, getdate ())
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `between` for this purpose.  I prefer to have code that works on both `date`s and `datetime`s without modification.

In addition, SQL Server has the convenient `datefromparts()` function.  So, I recomend:

```
WHERE date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
      date < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND
       date < CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. Also, please do not roll back edits which objectively improve your post, in this case by adding code formatting.